# Why are ref parameters not contravariant?

Tags: c#, ref, contravariance

This works:

```
EndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(_address, _port);
_socket.ReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, 1024, SocketFlags.None, ref endPoint);
```

But this does not:

```
IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(_address, _port);
_socket.ReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, 1024, SocketFlags.None, ref endPoint);
```

(Note the type of endPoint)

Which seems odd. Why does the ref keyword break parameter contravariance?

Comment: A better question is "why are out parameters not covariant?"  Out parameters are behind-the-scenes implemented exactly the same as ref parameters; all we do is change what definite assignment rules the compiler enforces. Since ref parameters can be both read from and written to, the type of the variable passed cannot vary either direction; since out parameters are just fancy ref parameters, they cannot vary either.

Comment: Thanks Eric, that makes a lot of sense. Ref is an interesting one, it seems like in a 'clean' implementation of C# we shouldn't really need it...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because in the method signature, the `endPoint` parameter is declared as `EndPoint`, not `IPEndPoint` ; there is no guarantee that the method won't set `endPoint` to another kind of `EndPoint`, which would not be assignable to a `IPEndPoint` variable.

For instance, assume you have a `FooEndPoint` class that inherits from `EndPoint`, and a `Foo` method that takes a `ref EndPoint` parameter :

```
public class FooEndPoint : EndPoint
{
   ...
}

public void Foo(ref EndPoint endPoint)
{
    ...
    endPoint = new FooEndPoint();
    ...
}
```

If you were able to pass a `IPEndPoint` to that method, the assigment of a `FooEndPoint` to the `endPoint` parameter would fail at runtime, because a `FooEndPoint` is not a `IPEndPoint`

Comment: I understand the logic behind your response and why they could decide to make a rule on this however I believe I'd agree with the poster since he's asking the question in the first place that it's an incorrect rule. The compiler at most should provide a warning that it's possible for an incorrect runtime assignment. But it should be left up to the developers to handle some type of incorrect exception instead of not being allowed.

Comment: Is this one of things that is addressed with the dynamic keyword in 4.0?

Comment: For a more extensive explanation, check out this post by Eric Lippert: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/09/21/why-do-ref-and-out-parameters-not-allow-type-variation.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Because the method ReceiveFrom can create a new EndPoint - but not IPEndPoint. This parameter works kind of in two ways, so the type needs to match exactly.

Answer (score 0):

The contraviariance is lose on `ref` and `out` parameters because they are references. That means when you pass a normal parameter to a method, CLR will solve that reference to a value and will pass that value as an argument, whereas when a parameter is either `ref` or `out` CLR will pass the whole reference as an argument. The reference type in .NET is `WeakReference<T>` and you're wrapping your reference in that.
The generic argument given to `WeakReference<T>` is the type your reference is, for example:

```
public void Test<T>(ref T reference)
{
    WeakReference<T> weakReference = __makeref(reference);
}
```

Now, I'm going deeper with another example:

```
public void Test(ref string reference)
{
    WeakReference<string> weakReference = __makeref(reference);
}
```

And this is one more:

```
public void Test(ref string reference)
{
    WeakReference<object> weakReference = __makeref(reference);
}
```

The latter example will give you a compiler error: as you can see, generic parameters are not contravariant. Therefore, when you wrap the reference of the parameter to a `WeakReference<T>`, `T` must be exactly the type of that parameter.

Even if you're not using `__makeref`, you could understand that the internal behavior of CLR is such a thing.
Furthermore, in a lower level references are structures containing the type of the value and the value itself. So, if you could cast a reference to any of its super types, you'll change the type of the reference and when you try to get its value, it fails because the type of the value is different by the type of the reference it's in.